# Command Line Utility for Starting Django Projects and Apps with Custom Files

Tags: python, unit-testing, django

#### What I'm Doing

I'm writing a command line utility for starting Django projects and apps with custom files.

The custom files build upon what Django offers, to make sure things like a custom auth user model and the ability to read environment variables from a `.env` file are added to projects from outset.

#### Why I'm Doing It

This is something I'm doing to get more acquainted with Django, and to improve my testing game — yes, that's why I'm writing a fruglier version of django-cookiecutter :).

#### What I'm Asking For

I would love to get some **brutally honest** review on my code. I'd especially appreciate it if you could please focus on the tests because that's the area in which I want to improve the most.

#### Important Files

**classy_start/start.py**

```
import enum
import pathlib
import subprocess
import sys
from typing import List, Optional

from . import file_contents, paths


@enum.unique
class Startable(enum.Enum):
    PROJECT = 0
    APP = 1


def _start(what: Startable, name: str, directory: Optional[str] = None):
    directive = f"start{what.name.lower()}"
    cmd: List[str]
    cmd = ["django-admin", directive, name]

    if directory is not None:
        cmd.append(directory)

    templates_dir_name = f"{what.name}_TEMPLATES_DIR"
    cmd.extend(["--template", str(getattr(paths, templates_dir_name))])

    try:
        subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        sys.exit(1)


def start_app(name: str, directory: Optional[str] = None):
    _start(Startable.APP, name, directory)


def start_project(name: str, directory: Optional[str] = None):
    _start(Startable.PROJECT, name, directory)

    follow_up_start_project(name, directory)


def follow_up_start_project(name: str, directory: Optional[str] = None):
    if directory is None:
        manage_dir = pathlib.Path(".") / name
    else:
        manage_dir = pathlib.Path(directory)

    manage_dir.resolve(strict=True)
    name_change_map = {
        "secrets.py": ".env",
        "gitignore.py": ".gitignore",
        "requirements.py": "requirements.txt",
    }

    for (old_name, new_name) in name_change_map.items():
        rename_file(old_name, new_name, base_dir=manage_dir)

    create_accounts_app(manage_dir)


def rename_file(old_name: str, new_name: str, base_dir: pathlib.Path):
    (base_dir / old_name).rename(base_dir / new_name)


def create_accounts_app(directory: pathlib.Path):
    dest = directory / "accounts"
    dest.mkdir()

    start_app("accounts", dest)

    for (filename, content) in [
        ("models.py", file_contents.auth_user_model_file_content),
        ("admin.py", file_contents.auth_user_admin_file_content),
    ]:
        write_file(dest / filename, content)


def write_file(file: pathlib.Path, content: str):
    file.touch()
    file.write_text(content)
```

**tests/test_start.py**

```
import pathlib
import random
import shlex
import string
from unittest import mock

import pytest

from classy_start.file_contents import (
    auth_user_model_file_content,
    auth_user_admin_file_content,
)
from classy_start.paths import APP_TEMPLATES_DIR, PROJECT_TEMPLATES_DIR
from classy_start.start import (
    start_app,
    start_project,
    follow_up_start_project,
    rename_file,
    create_accounts_app,
    write_file,
)

def test_start_app(fake_process):

    fake_process.keep_last_process(True)
    fake_process.register_subprocess([fake_process.any()])

    start_app("appify")

    count = fake_process.call_count(
        shlex.split(f"django-admin startapp appify --template '{APP_TEMPLATES_DIR!s}'")
    )
    assert count == 1


@mock.patch("classy_start.start.follow_up_start_project")
def test_start_project(mock_follow_up, fake_process):

    fake_process.keep_last_process(True)
    fake_process.register_subprocess([fake_process.any()])

    start_project("projectible", ".")

    count = fake_process.call_count(
        shlex.split(
            f"django-admin startproject projectible . --template '{PROJECT_TEMPLATES_DIR!s}'"
        )
    )
    assert count == 1

    mock_follow_up.assert_called_once_with("projectible", ".")


@mock.patch("pathlib.Path.resolve")
@mock.patch("classy_start.start.rename_file")
@mock.patch("classy_start.start.create_accounts_app")
def test_follow_up_start_project(
    mock_create_accounts_app, mock_rename_file, _mock_resolve
):
    """
    Assert that ~.follow_up_start_project() calls ~.rename_file() the correct number of
    times and with the correct arguments. And that it also calls
    ~.create_accounts_app() with the correct arguments.
    """
    follow_up_start_project("projectible")

    assert mock_rename_file.call_count == 3
    mock_rename_file.assert_has_calls(
        [
            mock.call("secrets.py", ".env", base_dir=pathlib.Path("projectible")),
            mock.call(
                "gitignore.py", ".gitignore", base_dir=pathlib.Path("projectible")
            ),
            mock.call(
                "requirements.py",
                "requirements.txt",
                base_dir=pathlib.Path("projectible"),
            ),
        ]
    )
    mock_create_accounts_app.assert_called_once_with(pathlib.Path("projectible"))

    # reset the **all used** mocks
    mock_rename_file.reset_mock()
    mock_create_accounts_app.reset_mock()

    follow_up_start_project("projectible", pathlib.Path("."))

    assert mock_rename_file.call_count == 3
    mock_rename_file.assert_has_calls(
        [
            mock.call("secrets.py", ".env", base_dir=pathlib.Path(".")),
            mock.call("gitignore.py", ".gitignore", base_dir=pathlib.Path(".")),
            mock.call(
                "requirements.py", "requirements.txt", base_dir=pathlib.Path("."),
            ),
        ]
    )
    mock_create_accounts_app.assert_called_once_with(pathlib.Path("."))


@mock.patch("pathlib.Path.rename")
def test_rename_file(mock_rename):
    """
    Assert that ~.rename_file() calls pathlib.Path.rename with the correct target.
    """
    base_dir = pathlib.Path(".") / "projectible"
    rename_file("old_name", "new_name", base_dir)

    mock_rename.assert_called_once_with(base_dir / "new_name")


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "manage_dir", [pathlib.Path("."), pathlib.Path(".") / "projectible"]
)
@mock.patch("pathlib.Path.mkdir")
@mock.patch("classy_start.start.start_app")
@mock.patch("classy_start.start.write_file")
def test_create_accounts_app(mock_write_file, mock_start_app, _mock_mkdir, manage_dir):
    """
    Assert that ~.create_accoung_app() calls ~.start_app() with the
    correct arguments. And that it calls pathlib.Path.write_text the
    correct number of times and with the correct arguments.
    """
    create_accounts_app(manage_dir)

    accounts_app_dir = manage_dir / "accounts"
    model_file = accounts_app_dir / "models.py"
    admin_file = accounts_app_dir / "admin.py"

    mock_start_app.assert_called_once_with("accounts", accounts_app_dir)

    assert mock_write_file.call_count == 2
    assert mock_write_file.has_calls(
        [
            mock.call(model_file, auth_user_model_file_content,),
            mock.call(admin_file, auth_user_admin_file_content,),
        ]
    )


@mock.patch("pathlib.Path.touch")
@mock.patch("pathlib.Path.write_text")
def test_write_file(mock_write_text, mock_touch):
    file = pathlib.Path("project") / "app" / "an_app_file.py"
    content = "".join(random.sample(string.printable, 64))

    write_file(file, content)

    mock_touch.assert_called_once()
    mock_write_text.assert_called_once_with(content)
```

### GitHub Repository

https://github.com/mfonism/django-classy-start